# Routing to show action on logout

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a logout link that should be routing to users#do_logout but no matter what I do, if I click the link, it routes to the users#show. Here is the code:

Route:

```
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :profile
      post :profile
    end
    collection do
      get "signup", to: 'users#new'
      get "login"
      post "do_login"
      post "do_logout"
    end
  end
```

Link:

```
li = link_to "Sign Out", do_logout_users_path
```

Users controller action:

```
  def do_logout
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to :root
  end
```

Any help would be much appreciated. This is driving me insane.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because, you have set up a `POST` route for `do_logout` and your Sign Out link is making a `GET` request.

To do a `POST` request from the view, you have to create a form

```
= form_tag do_logout_users_path do
  = submit_tag 'Sign Out'
```

**OR**

You could use `delete` method for this

in routes

```
delete "do_logout"
```

and the link

```
= link_to "Sign Out", do_logout_users_path, :method => :delete
```

Comment: I tried that and it's still doing the same thing. It's like it is incapable of hitting the logout route, and defaults to the show.